# Delete repeated values of different data types from cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, unique, cell

I have a list of cell array with many repeated values, which includes strings, sample time, saturation upper limit and lower limit.

For example:

```
MyValues={  'Lookc_at_the_stars'
            'Lookc_how_they_shine'
            'forc_you'
            'andm_everything_they_do'
            'Theym_were_all_yellow'
            'COLDPLAY_STOP'
            'COLDPLAY_PLAY'
            'COLDPLAY_PLAY'
            'COLDPLAY_PLAY'
            'COLDPLAY_BREAK'
            'COLDPLAY_BREAK'
            'Lookc_How_they_shinefor_you'
            'its_true'
            'COLDPLAY_STOP'
            'COLDPLAY_STOP'   }
```

And the output what I require is:

```
NewMyValues = { 'Lookc_at_the_stars'
                'Lookc_how_they_shine'
                'forc_you'
                'andm_everything_they_do'
                'Theym_were_all_yellow'
                'COLDPLAY_STOP'
                'COLDPLAY_PLAY'
                'COLDPLAY_BREAK'
                'Lookc_How_they_shinefor_you'
                'its_true'  }
```

Since I have tried using the function `unique`, I am not able to get the output as it's giving me an error, saying

> "Error using cell/unique 
>   
> Input A must be a cell array of strings."

`MyValues` consists of different types of data type values.

Can someone provide me a solution or function code, that I could remove the repeated values?

Comment: Create a [MCVE]

Comment: Which version of Matlab are you using? `unique(MyValues, 'stable')` works in Matlab 2015b.

Comment: In the example you've provided, there are only strings. It would have been better if you had provided the example containing *strings, sample time, saturation upper limit and lower limit* as you wrote that your actual data contained all of them.

Comment: Hi @Jørgen I am using the same version Matlab 2015b, and its giving the same error

Comment: @MohammedNadaf This is because your actual data doesn't contain only strings. Jørgen's answer will work if your data contains only strings. You should've provided a better example of your data covering all the aspects that you mentioned which are:  *strings, sample time, saturation upper limit and lower limit*

Comment: @Sardar_Usama I apologize, but thank you for editing it, I was considering through my work point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a loop based solution to extract unique values of a cell array will different types:

```
MyValues={  'Lookc_at_the_stars',
            'Lookc_how_they_shine',
            1,
            'forc_you',
            'andm_everything_they_do',
            'Theym_were_all_yellow',
            2,
            'COLDPLAY_STOP',
            'COLDPLAY_PLAY',
            1,
            'COLDPLAY_PLAY',
            'COLDPLAY_PLAY',
            {1 2 3},
            'COLDPLAY_BREAK',
            {4 3 5},
            'COLDPLAY_BREAK',
            {1 2 3},
            'Lookc_How_they_shinefor_you',
            'its_true',
            'COLDPLAY_STOP',
            'COLDPLAY_STOP'   };
N = numel(MyValues);
idx = true(N,1);
for m = 1: N
    if idx(m)
        for n = (m+1):N
            if idx(n) && isequal(MyValues{m}, MyValues{n})
                idx(n) = false;
            end
        end
    end
end
result = MyValues(idx);
```

the result:

```
result =
{
  [1,1] = Lookc_at_the_stars
  [1,2] = Lookc_how_they_shine
  [1,3] =  1
  [1,4] = forc_you
  [1,5] = andm_everything_they_do
  [1,6] = Theym_were_all_yellow
  [1,7] =  2
  [1,8] = COLDPLAY_STOP
  [1,9] = COLDPLAY_PLAY
  [1,10] =
  {
    [1,1] =  1
    [1,2] =  2
    [1,3] =  3
  }
  [1,11] = COLDPLAY_BREAK
  [1,12] =
  {
    [1,1] =  4
    [1,2] =  3
    [1,3] =  5
  }
  [1,13] = Lookc_How_they_shinefor_you
  [1,14] = its_true
}
```

The function `isequal` can compare anything using it all values compared and duplicates removed. so `result` is a cell array that contains unique values.
Based on the example in the question if you  want to have unique cell array of characters you can use `cellfun` with `ischar` to check if the cell value  is a character array. Then use the logical index to extract them and apply `unique`.

```
unique(MyValues(cellfun(@ischar,MyValues)),'stable')
```

without using `stable` option the result will be sorted

Comment: Does not give the order required.

Comment: The OP's data can have *sample time, saturation upper limit and lower limit* which this code would ignore if they are of any other than `char` type. He wants to remove the duplicates of that data too.

Comment: I copied pasted the OP's words from his question for you where that is clearly written. Also the conversation between the OP and Jørgen in the comments under the question shows that.  P.S I am not the downvoter here

Comment: I nearly know the mysterious downvoter:). If so `containers.Map` is useful. unfortunately octave doesn't have this container You can post an answer

Comment: I am not much familiar with that. If you have some code to check and don't have MATLAB, I can run that for you. That's all I can offer

Comment: It seems that containers.map doesn't accept anything as key

Comment: Hi @rahnema1 I tried the loop function, and it works, I dont see any error and I am getting the output what I require. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you @Sardar_Usama for your support.

Answer (score 0):

The cell you supplied in your question only contained strings, so `unique` can handle it. However, if you add ints, floats or complex numbers to it, the way to go is to convert all the cell elements to strings before calling unique. For example, I'll show you a small `strcaster` function

```
function y = strcaster(x)
    if ischar(x)
        y = x;
    elseif isreal(x)
        y = num2str(x);
    else
        if imag(x)>=0
            s = '+j';
        else
            s = '-j';
        end
        y = [num2str(real(x)),s,num2str(imag(x))];
    end
end
```

and then you can get the unique elements, preserving the order in which they appear in the cell doing the following:

```
MyValues={'Lookc_at_the_stars',...
'Lookc_how_they_shine',...
'forc_you',...
'andm_everything_they_do',...
'Theym_were_all_yellow',...
'COLDPLAY_STOP',...
'COLDPLAY_PLAY',...
'COLDPLAY_PLAY',...
'COLDPLAY_PLAY',...
'COLDPLAY_BREAK',...
'COLDPLAY_BREAK',...
'Lookc_How_they_shinefor_you',...
'its_true',...
'COLDPLAY_STOP',...
'COLDPLAY_STOP',...
1,...
1.32423,...
complex(-3.,13)};
[u,i] = unique(cellfun(@(x)strcaster(x),MyValues,'uniformoutput',false),'stable');
disp(MyValues(i))
```

---

Edit

Based on your comment, it is clear that the `MyValues` cell contains other cells, which was not clear from your question's example. The best way to get the unique values in `MyValues` is still casting the contents to strings. The JSON protocol will allow you to convert almost any data type to a string, so I recommend using matlab's [jsonencode](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsonencode.html) function in the following way:

```
MyValues={'Lookc_at_the_stars',...
'Lookc_how_they_shine',...
'forc_you',...
'andm_everything_they_do',...
'Theym_were_all_yellow',...
'COLDPLAY_STOP',...
'COLDPLAY_PLAY',...
'COLDPLAY_PLAY',...
'COLDPLAY_PLAY',...
'COLDPLAY_BREAK',...
'COLDPLAY_BREAK',...
'Lookc_How_they_shinefor_you',...
'its_true',...
'COLDPLAY_STOP',...
'COLDPLAY_STOP',...
1,...
1.32423,...
[1,23,4,4;5,3,2,1],...
{'bla',1324,{'12',123}},...
struct('NextTime','Provide a complete working example in the question')};
[u,i] = unique(cellfun(@(x)jsonencode(x),MyValues,'uniformoutput',false),'stable');
disp(MyValues(i))
```

Comment: Hi @lucianopaz , I am getting error while using your function strcaster(x), it says: "Undefined function 'imag' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in strcaster 
        if imag(x)>=0

Error in as>@(x)strcaster(x)

Error in as 
[u,i] = unique(cellfun(@(x)strcaster(x),ParameterValues,'uniformoutput',false),'stable')"

Comment: Of course you get an error. The strcaster function I wrote was not made to handle, structs, cells or matrices. However, this can be done changing it slightly to use json to convert anything to a string. If you had provided a complete working example, showing you had cells, I would have used json from the start.