# Select unique rows of a numerical cell arrays in Matlab when rows have different sizes

Tags: matlab

I have a numerical cell array `A` in Matlab  of size `Mx3`.

I want to select the unique rows of the cell.

One of the problems is that the cell components may have different sizes.

For example,

```
A{1,1}=[1 1];
A{1,2}=3;
A{1,3}=[4 4 4 4];

A{2,1}=0;
A{2,2}=[10 10];
A{2,3}=7;

A{3,1}=[1 1];
A{3,2}=3;
A{3,3}=[4 4 4 4];
```

The output should be

```
B{1,1}=[1 1];
B{1,2}=3;
B{1,3}=[4 4 4 4];

B{2,1}=0;
B{2,2}=[10 10];
B{2,3}=7;
```

In my actual case `M=27000`.

Comment: A loop based solution is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41244060/6579744) . You can set `MyValues = num2cell(A,2);` and apply the method.

Comment: @rahnema1 The double loop takes too much with `M=27000`.

Comment: When dealing with cell-arrays containing different sort of data, a (for/while) loop or loop-wrappers (like `arrayfun`, `cellfun`) can always be expected for doing different operations.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the cell array into a matrix of [Datahashes](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31272-datahash?focused=8037540&tab=function).

Then, check the [Unique Rows](https://la.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/331309-matlab-find-unique-column-combinations-in-matrix-and-respective-index), as usually.

```
opt.Method='MD2';   % Select the cheapest one
opt.Format='uint8'; % Select a numeric one
b=arrayfun(@(x)sum(GEN.checksum(x,opt)),A,'uni',true)

[~,i]=unique(b(:,1),'rows')
Au=A{i,:,:}
```

You can apply this to only the first column, and move deeper after that.